# Incrementing register in MIPS assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-registers

I'm writing a MIPS program to sort 8 ascii atrings, the addresses of which are in registers $t0-7. When comparing two strings, I need to pass the addresses into a function (by saving into $s0 and $s1). If I want to do this in a loop, how can I increment the register values? Can I do this? Or do I need to put the addresses all in memory instead?

For example, if my loop is like this, in pseudocode:

```
for loop with index i:
 move address from register j into $s0
 move address from register j+1 into $s1
 call function for return value
 use return value to perform swapping operation
 increment i
 jump back to loop if i<bound
```

Where j is arbitrary, I'm just showing how I need to retrieve from two consecutive registers.

Is there a way to use offset notation for registers like you can with memory locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is there a way to use offset notation for registers like you can with memory locations?"

No ! Access to registers are hardcoded in assembly instructions. You can't access to a computed register.

Comment: Can you suggest a simple alternative? I'm not sure how to go about finding a solution.

Comment: Just put the 8 addresses in the addresses `$t0-7` in memory.

Comment: I figured that would be the only solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To increment a register, add 1 to it. Like this:

```
addiu $t0, $t0, 1
```

There are many registers on MIPS. If you don't want to trash the base address in some register, use another register for the base+offset, and increment it as necessary. Or use a third register as loop counter, and recalculate base+offset as necessary.

Comment: The question isn't very clear, but I've the impression that the OP wants to access register $t.i where `i` is in another register. So I don't think you answer the question.

Comment: hivert has the right idea--I essentially want a way to cycle through the registers as I would seperate memory locations.

Comment: I see. Short of generating code on the fly, there's no way. I assume it's some kind of a "dump all registers" scenario. Is it too hard to hand-unroll the loop? There are only 32 of them, not hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

You can if you really want to, by using self-modifying code. But I doubt you want to, would probably wreak havoc on the cache and produce overhead bit-twiddling the machine instructions.